# Parallel 10 HTTP Request

Tags: java, php

We have dynamics offer system and have to make 10 requests / per user and get result in 2000ms. (concurrent user 1k)

I have tried [parallel command](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html), curl multi, java HttpURLConnection with thread and [Apache connection management](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) but couldn't work in 2000ms on dedicated server which have 32 core and 64gb RAM. My best stat is 130 concurrent user and average response time 4 seconds.

We're using php and java but we can't find right way for it. Have you any idea for right way?

Additional Information : I can reach 7k user with only 1 http request every user

Comment: What is your average response time of a single request?

Comment: @Tsanyo average is 100ms. thanks

Comment: You're spawning 100,000 API calls with an average response time of 100ms and expecting a response time of 2 seconds ? How will that work ? Split your workload horizontally across your servers and work on improving the response time.

Comment: @DeepakBala my fault .. i wanted to write 1k user :)

Comment: Even if you have 10k API requests per second, you're not going to reach the throughput and response times you are looking for. Load test a single server and check what throughput you can achieve from it. Then scale your system horizontally to handle that load statelessly across N servers.

Comment: I agree with @DeepakBala, you need to work on lowering your response times or just use more servers.